# Replace text nodes

Tags: javascript, css, forms, dom

I'm trying to replace these two text nodes with each other. It suppose to be like a correction verification. What its suppose to do is to see if the input is correct after you focus on another input.

This is the html

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Lab Group Form</legend>
                <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                <br/>
            <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name_text" value="" onblur="validatefirst()" />
                    <br/><br/>
          </fieldset>
</form> 

 <div class="one" id="one"/>
 <div class="two" id="two"/>
</body>



    function validatefirst() {
        if (document.myform.first_name.value.length > 0) {
            var one = document.createTextNode("Correct");
            var one_container = document.getElementById("one");

        } else {
            var two = document.createTextNode("Incorrect.");
            var two_container = document.getElementById("two");
            two_container.appendChild(two);
        }
    }
```

this is the css file:

```
.one { 
    color:#000; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:400px;
}


.two{ 
    color:#000; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:14px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:400px; 
}
```

So if you can help me out that will be great. Please no jquery. Thank you

Comment: The fieldset and both divs need end tags, before you even start on the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you're trying to accomplish with the function-within-a-function. The following does something, not sure if it's what you want or not:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one { 
    color:#000; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:200px;
}


.two{ 
    color:#000; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:14px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:200px; 
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Lab Group Form</legend>
                <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                <br/>
            <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name_text" onchange="validatefirst()" />
                    <br/><br/>
          </fieldset>
</form> 

 <div class="one" id="one"/>
 <div class="two" id="two"/>
</body>
<script>
    function validatefirst() {
        if (document.getElementById("first_name").value.length > 0) {
            var one = document.createTextNode("Correct");
            var one_container = document.getElementById("one");
            one_container.appendChild(one);
        } else {
            var two = document.createTextNode("Incorrect.");
            var two_container = document.getElementById("two");
            two_container.appendChild(two);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```